# Checkout multiple projects at SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have the following SVN structure:

```
/Project1
    /trunk
        ( Shared code between all clients of project 1 )
    /branches
        Client1
            ( Specific code for version project 1 of the client 1 )
        Client2
            ( Specific code for version project 1 of the client 2 )
    /tags
    ...


/Project2
    /trunk
        ( Shared code between all clients of project 2 )
    /branches
        Client1
            ( Specific code for version project 2 of the client 1 )
        Client2
            ( Specific code for version project 2 of the client 2 )
    /tags
    ...


/Shared
    /trunk
        ( Shared code between project 1 and project 2 )
    /branches
        ...
    /tags
    ...
```

And I would like to know if it's possible to checkout automatically both  `Project1 / trunk` and  `Shared / trunk` when I checkout `Project1 / branches / Client1`, in order to have the following structure at wwwroot:

```
/Project1_Client1
    ( Specific code for version project 1 of the client 1 )
    ( Shared code between all clients of project 1 )
    ( Shared code between project 1 and project 2 )
```

Comment: Hrmm, sounds like you could probably coerce svn:externals into doing the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you have to do to get your solution (thanks to the tips of @Corbin and @Lazy_Badget, look at the [documentation of SVN red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals)):

1. Add to the directory `/Project1/branches/Client1` the following externals definition:

   ```
   /Project1/trunk Client1All
   /Shared/trunk Shared
   ```
2. As a result, you should get when checking out the directory `/Project1/branches/Client1` as directory `Project1_Client1` the following local structure:

   ```
   /Project1_Client1
     ... all the subdirectories as usual
     /Client1All
     /Shared
   ```